# Can not send POST with body

Tags: java, angular, cors

I have issue in my application. I have various REST enpoints which are working fine. But now I want to send POST request with body. I already have 2 endpoints for POST method, but data are send using PathParam.

I created new endpoint, but when I send request I am getting CORS error. When I use the same endpoint without body in request everything is okay but of course at backend side I do not get any data from frontend (I have breakpoint inside method).

this is how I send request from my angular application:

```
post(requestUrl: string, body?: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.API_URL + requestUrl, {password: 'test'});
}
```

After sending request I got:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/...' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If I send request like this (without body) this endpoint works fine:

```
post(requestUrl: string, body?: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.API_URL + requestUrl);
}
```

At backend side I have added settings for CORS:

```
return Response.ok(object).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
      .allow("OPTIONS").build();
```

When I am sending request from Insomnia everything is ok - I can send body and I am getting sent data on backend.

Should I somehow set request headers at frontend side?

Here is my AdminApiController class:

```
@Path("/admin")
@RequestScoped
public class AdminApiController extends BaseApiController {

@Inject
private AdminAssembler adminAssembler;

@POST
@Path("/login")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(LoginRequest request) {
  return Response.ok(adminAssembler.login(request))
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
      .allow("OPTIONS").build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your angular application sends a JSON payload in a POST request, it probably adds the header `Content-Type: application/json`. This header classifies the POST request as a "non-simple" request (that is, a request that cannot result out of an HTML `<form>` element without additional Javascript). Such "non-simple" requests cause to browser to make a preceding preflight request, that is an OPTIONS request with headers

```
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type
```

to which the server must respond with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`. If it does not, the browser will not make the POST request and show an error like you observed.

Your Java code covers only `@POST`, not `@OPTIONS`, that's why the server does *not* respond to the preflight request with the necessary headers. How best to handle the OPTIONS requests for *all* endpoints on your server is a question for Java experts (which I am not).

Comment: I do not mentioned this, but I already tried this solution. But now for double check I added `.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")` but this does not help

Comment: What Java class is this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I added my controller class to first post

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Ok, so now when I added new endpoint with OPTIONS annotation, it works. So thank you with your help. But my next question is - have I add this OPTIONS to all my future endpoints? Is there any way to do this simpler?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your httpOptions.
Try this.

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
};

post(requestUrl: string, body?: any): Observable<any> {
  this.httpClient.post<any>(this.API_URL + requestUrl, {password: 'test'}, this.httpOptions)
}
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: this is not working

Comment: So the problem is with the server